# Python Beautifulsoup findAll finds some but not all

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

With a bit of Python knowledge I tried to do some LinkedIn company posts scraping.

Using the code below, that I took from [this website](https://christophegaron.com/scraping-linkedin-posts-with-selenium-and-beautiful-soup/), all posts on a company's LinkedIn page are found first before its contents are extracted. The issue is that I know, I've counted, that there are more posts than that the `findAll` function returns, regardless of which of the parsers `lxml`, `html5lib` or `html.parser` I use. In one case, it returns 43 out of 67 posts, in another case it returns 10 out of 14. Typically, it finds about 3 or 4, then it skips 4 or 5 posts, then it finds a few again, etc.

How can I find out why this is happening?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# Import
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Get credentials to log in to LinkedIn
username = input('Enter your linkedin username: ')
password = input('Enter your linkedin password: ')
company_name = input('Name of the company: ')

# Access Webdriver
s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
browser.maximize_window()

# Define page to open
page = "https://www.linkedin.com/company/{}/posts/?feedView=all".format(company_name)

# Open login page
browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin')

# Enter login info:
elementID = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
elementID.send_keys(username)
elementID = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
elementID.send_keys(password)
elementID.submit()

# Go to webpage
browser.get(page + 'posts/')

# Define scrolling time
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1.5

# Get scroll height
last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

# Scroll all the way to the bottom of the page
while True:

    # Scroll down to bottom
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

# Get content of page
content = browser.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()

# Create soup
linkedin_soup = bs(content, "html5lib")
linkedin_soup.prettify()

# Find entities that contain posts
containers = linkedin_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"occludable-update ember-view"})
```

Comment: which company is giving you 10 of 14 so I can debug/test it out.

Comment: If you are using a good IDE such as [pyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), the built-in debugger should be able to help you out.

Comment: The 10/14 was taniq. I'm using Visual Studio which also has a debugger, I've been using it but cannot find out why.

Comment: @chitown88 did you get a chance to try to debug? I'd really appreciate it! If you replace `company_name` by taniq it should work I believe, otherwise let me know.

Comment: Oh no I did not. I didn't realize you replied in the comment. I'll do that today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when you scroll down to the bottom, it sort of skips some of the posts to render. There likely a better way to do this, but basically I have scroll 1/4 of the way, then 1/2, then full (hoping to catch all the posts). Try this adjustment:

```
# Scroll all the way to the bottom of the page
while True:

    # Scroll down to bottom
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/4);")
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2);")
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Comment: Wow who could believe that the answer is this "stupid", I facepalmed myself... many thanks! Your suggestion got me on the right track, I had to make some adjustments, I posted it as a another answer, but you have my acceptance :)

Comment: no worries mate. Not stupid at all. Sometime just need another set of eyes to look. Your implimentation is nice though. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

So @chitown88 got me on the right track, this is the final code I have now which gets me the result I need:

```
# Define scrolling height and time
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1.5 # [sec]
SCROLL_HEIGHT = 1000

# Pause to be sure page is loaded
time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

# Scroll all the way to the bottom of the page
new_height = SCROLL_HEIGHT
while True:

    # Get maximal scroll height
    max_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    # Check whether maximal scroll height has been exceeded
    if new_height > max_height:
        break

    # Scroll to position
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(new_height))
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Get current scroll position
    #current_height = browser.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset")

    # Increase scroll position
    new_height = new_height + SCROLL_HEIGHT

# Make sure to reach last position
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(max_height))
```

I left in the `current_height` variable, not sure if I'll need it again, this code needs some more verification. Useful to save maybe.